# Jenkins artifactory release management plugin with mvn versions:use-releases

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

"mvn versions:use-releases (mvn goals)" remove the "SNAPSHOT" word on your dependencies, ONLY / DURING the specific build you've triggered, not modifying or parsing your pom.xml on the repo itself (like gitlab) this could be very helpful when using artifactory release management plugin because this process doesn't allow projects with SNAPSHOT word on pom.xml, however I have tried using the mvn versions:use-releases when doing a release on artifactory release plugin, but the build is failing due to the build read 1st the pom.xml (with snapshot) before executing the mvn goals that will remove the snapshot word, even I tried to put the mvn goals on the alternative maven goals and options under "enable artifactory release management"

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed exceptions / if else condition on deleting word on xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615981/sed-exceptions-if-else-condition-on-deleting-word-on-xml)